# Expand array elements

Tags: json, list, kotlin

How to expand an array of objects containing an array of strings into an array of strings?
I have:

```
data class MyClass (
  @JsonProperty("applicant") val applicant: String,
  val products: List<Product>
) {
  fun getCiss(): List<String> = products........

  companion object {
    data class Product(
      val cises: List<String>)
  }
}
```

I have this JSON as request:

```
{"applicant": "11111111",
"products": [
  {
     "cises":["111"]
  }, {
     "cises":["222", "333"]
  }
]
}
```

How can I convert List of Product to List of String in getCiss function? It should turn out: ["111", "222", "333"]

I try like this:

```
fun getCiss(): List<String> = products.stream().map { Product::cises }.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but my assumption is that you have a list of products and each product has a list of "cises" and you want to get a single list containing all "cises".

If that's the case, then you should use [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html). This function allows you to transform a collection of A into a collection of collection of B, and it "flattens" the collection of collections of B into a single collection of B. Basically it applies a transformation from A to a collection of B first, and then it flattens the result.

Example:

```
data class Product(val cises: List<String>)

fun main() {
    // simulate a list of products
    val products = listOf(
            Product(listOf("111")),
            Product(listOf("222", "333"))
    )
    println(products)
    // get a list of all "cises" from all products
    val cises = products.flatMap { it.cises }
    println(cises)
}
```

output:

```
[Product(cises=[111]), Product(cises=[222, 333])]
[111, 222, 333]
```